# How to parse a string of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am working with an API that is returning a "JSON string"...which means that it's returning text wrapped with double quotes:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://api.example.com')
response.body == '"token"'
```

For all of my requests, I am abstracting the API request and automatically using `JSON.parse(response.body)`, but in this case, it chokes on the string because it's not a JSON object.

I guess I can add an extra logic branch to check if it's a string, don't parse as JSON. How should I extract the string out of this string?

Comment: `response.body[1..-2]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use regex

```
s = '"token"'
str = s[/\A"(.+)"\Z/, 1]
puts str # => token
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
JSON.parse(response.body) rescue response.body[1..-2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not sniff for the normal JSON open/close characters `[`...`]` and `{`...`}` used to define objects?

Here's how objects look converted to JSON:

```
require 'json'

puts JSON[{'foo' => 1}]
puts JSON[[1, 2]]
# >> {"foo":1}
# >> [1,2]
```

Checking to make sure those are valid string representations:

```
JSON['{"foo":1}'] # => {"foo"=>1}
JSON['[1,2]'] # => [1, 2]
```

Here's how I'd write some code to sniff whether the string passed in looks like a valid JSON string, or just a string with wrapping double-quotes:

```
require 'json'

def get_object(str)
  if str[/^[{\[].+[}\]]$/]
    JSON[str]
  else
    str[1..-2]
  end
end

get_object('{"foo":1}') # => {"foo"=>1}
get_object('{"foo":1}').class # => Hash
get_object('[1,2]') # => [1, 2]
get_object('[1,2]').class # => Array
get_object("'bar'") # => "bar"
```

Notice that on the last line the string `'bar'` that's enclosed in single-quotes, is returned as a bare string, i.e., there is no wrapping set of single-quotes so the string is no longer quoted.

It's possible you'd receive a string with white-space leading or following the payload. If so, do something like:

```
def get_object(str)
  if str.strip[/^[{\[].+[}\]]$/]
    JSON[str]
  else
    str.strip[1..-2]
  end
end

get_object('  {"foo":1}') # => {"foo"=>1}
get_object('  [1,2]  ') # => [1, 2]
get_object(" 'bar'") # => "bar"
```